# SEO using .htaccess? And, how to redirect a fake subdirectory to an individual page?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

Since a recent redesign of our website, we've noticed that the search rankings for certain pages has plummeted as individual publications are no longer on their own page, but rather on `publications.php?magazine=xx`, where `xx` is a unique ID number for the publication.

Is there any way to use a `.htaccess` file to redirect fake subdirectories to the pages, i.e. visiting `/publications/magazine-name` takes you to `publications.php?magazine=xx`, and if so: would this even have an effect on their SEO?

If not, is there any other way you can make these URL query strings more search engine-friendly?

Comment: You should have `magazine id` also in the pretty URL e.g. `/publications//magazine-id/magazine-name` same as Stackoverflow URL scheme

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: There are two questions within my post - one regarding SEO, one regarding mod_rewrite within a .htaccess file. As such, I have tagged this post with both `SEO` and `.htaccess`; What more could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only halfway there, but using the `mod_rewrite` tool with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^advanced-lift-truck?$ pub-automotive.php?mag=1 [NC,L]
```

can get me a URL that Google will understand and trawl.

Now, it's just a case of figuring out what I can do about each page effectively having the same "content", just with different CSS showing/hiding parts.

I'm investigating the following:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/10/how-to-optimize-single-page-sites-for-search-engines/